# Understanding the Details of the Construction of the Tensor Product

Tags: tensor-products

This is essentially a follow-up on this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51155/understanding-of-the-tensor-product-of-vector-spaces). Specifically, I'm studying the construction of the tensor product of two vector spaces as indicated by the OP's 2nd definition. Namely, that the tensor product of two vector spaces $V$ and $W$ is the quotient space $V \times W / E$ where $E$ is the subspace of $V \times W$ generated by linear combinations of the form

$$
(v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1, w) - (v_2, w)
$$
$$
(v, w_1 + w_2) - (v, w_1) - (v, w_2)
$$
$$
(av, w) - a(v,w)
$$
$$
(v,aw) - a(v,w)
$$

We also denote an element of this quotient space by $v \otimes w$. Now, I'm trying to understand precisely why it follows from this construction that, for example, $(v_1 + v_2) \otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w$. I believe it follows from the following argument:

First, we note that

$$
(v_1 + v_2, w) - (v_1, w) - (v_2, w) = (v_1 + v_2, w) - ((v_1, w) + (v_2, w))
$$

By definition of what it means to be a quotient space, this last equation means that

$$
[ (v_1 + v_2, w)] = [(v_1, w) + (v_2, w)]
$$

where $[ \cdot ]$ denotes the induced equivalence class. But, according to the definition of the $\otimes$ operator, we can express this equality as

$$
(v_1 + v_2) \otimes w = v_1 \otimes w + v_2 \otimes w
$$

Is this argument valid and is this the appropriate way to think about these things?

Comment: Be careful! This is not a quotient of $V \times W$. You want to form the [free vector space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_module) on the set $V \times W$.

Comment: Here's one thing: It's not the space $V \times W$ but rather the space (freely) generated by the set of symbols $[v,w]$ with $v \in V$ and $w \in W$. You'll probably have heard that $\dim{V \otimes W} = \dim{V} \cdot \dim{W}$, while $\dim{V \times W} = \dim{V} + \dim{W}$, so it can't be $V \times W$.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have a couple of misconceptions here.

First, the tensor product is not defined as a quotient of the vector space $V\times W$. Rather, you consider a vector space $Z$ whose basis elements *are* the elements of $V\times W$. So, for example, if $V=W=\mathbb{R}$, you would have one basis element for $(1,0)$, *another* basis element for $(2,0)$, *another* basis element for $(3,0)$, etc. That is why in that post they are written with double brackets, so as not to confuse $Z$ with $V\times W$.

Note that this is *way* bigger than $V\times W$. The vector space $V\times W$ has dimension $\dim(V)+\dim(W)$. The vector space $Z$ has dimension $|V\times W|$, which is, usually, much larger! For $V=W=\mathbb{R}$, $V\times W$ has dimension $2$, but $Z$ has dimension $\mathfrak{c}=2^{\aleph_0}$.

So you have one basis element for *each* element of $V\times W$; you should think of $V\times W$ as the index set for the basis. The basis element $[[v,w]]$ is the basis element that corresponds to the element $(v,w)$ of $V\times W$.

Then $E$ is the subspace of $Z$ *generated* be all the relations you write down; so, in my example above, you would have the vector $2[[1,0]]-[[2,0]]$ in $E$, etc.

Now, the image of the basis vector $[[v,w]]$ in the quotient is denoted by $v\otimes w$. So in general it's not every vector of $Z/E$ that can be written as $v\otimes w$: these are only the images of the basis of $Z$. So you know that these elements generate $Z/E$, but they need not be all of $Z/E$ (in general, they won't be). The elements of $Z/E$ are linear combinations of these "pure tensors" $v\otimes w$.

So, why does it follow from the construction that $(v_1+v_2)\otimes w = (v_1\otimes w) + (v_2\otimes w)$?

This equality is saying that the equivalence class of $[[v_1+v_2,w]]$ is the same as the equivalence class of $[[v_1,w]]+[[v_2,w]]$ in the quotient. By definition of quotient, this is the same as saying that the vector
$$[[v_1+v_2,w]] - [[v_1,w]] - [[v_2,w]]$$
of $Z$ lies in the subspace $E$. But it lies in the subspace $E$ because it is one of the generating elements of $E$. So the equality holds in $Z/E$.

Comment: Thanks for the elaboration; I guess the major thing I was missing is that we consider the *free* vector space generated by all $(v,w) \in V \times W$ and then quotient that space with $E$.

Comment: @Arturo What do the double brackets signify? You use them first in paragraph 4 when you write $[[v,w]]$?

Comment: @Arturo How can I prove that exists a vector space $Z$ whose basis elements are the elements of $V\times W$? It is difficult for me to imagine a vector space $Z$ in which the elements of $V\times W$ are linearly independent.

Comment: @rfloc: not difficult at all. It's a set; you can define a vector space with any given set as a basis. What you need to remember is to **forget** that $V\times W$ is a vector space. You are only looking at it as a set of labels, and sticking each member of the set on an abstract vector to be your basis. Think of vectors of the form $\mathbf{a}_{(v,w)}$, with $\mathbf{a}_{(v,w)}=\mathbf{a}_{(v',w')}$ if and only if $(v,w)=(v',w')$. and your vector space just consists of finite linear combinations of these vectors.

Comment: Forgive me if I ask a stupid question, but since $V=W=\mathbb{R}$, should the dimension of $\mathbb{Z}$ be $\aleph_{1}^2$ instead of $2^{\aleph_{0}}$?

Comment: @luyuwuli the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is $2^{\aleph_0}$. Whether it equals $\aleph_1$ or something else us the Continuum Hypothesis, which is independent of ZFC set theory. Whether you take it to be $2^{\aleph_0}$ or $\aleph_1$, its square equals itself.

Comment: Ahh, I see. Thank you for your reply.