# Understanding Tensor product of modules

Tags: modules, tensor-products

This is follow up question 
[Understanding the Details of the Construction of the Tensor Product](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61916/understanding-the-details-of-the-construction-of-the-tensor-product/61919#61919?newreg=c7f06e30fe484c559462b3b8c128f8e9)

If $M$ and $N$ are 2 A-modules, we define $Z = A^{M\times N}$ as module generated by $M\times N$.
Then $D$ is sub-module of $Z$ defined with some relations as described above.

I am not understanding why these relations are like that. It can be simplified as --
$(v+v_1,w) - (v,w) - (v_1,w)  \implies (0,-w)$ 
and similarly for other 3 conditions

As per my understanding, $Z/D$ is set of cosets of $D$. If $(v,w)$ belongs to $Z$ then its corresponding coset will be $(v,w) + D$. 
What is meant by image of $(v,w)$ ?

Comment: Please reread your question and fix LaTeX errors, e.g., write $\times$ instead of $x$ and insert the missing subscript.

Comment: Your question indicates that you are not wholly comfortable with quotients of modules. Without this comfort, you will find tensor products and later topics very difficult. So I would advice you read some more about quotients and do as many exercises on the topic that you can find.