# Isomorphism between tensor product of dual space and space of bilinear maps

Tags: tensor-products

I am trying to show $V^* \otimes W^* \simeq L_2(V \times W,\mathbb{R})$ using the definition [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116561/clarification-of-definition-of-tensor-product).

Hence I try to show $\phi:V^* \otimes W^* \to L_2(V \times W,\mathbb{R})$ defined by $\phi(\alpha\otimes \beta)=\Phi_{\alpha,\beta}$, where $\Phi_{\alpha,\beta}(v,w)=\alpha(v)\beta(w)$ is an isomorphism. If I assume $\phi$ is a linear map, I can show it's bijective. But I don't know how to show the linearity of $\phi$, in particular, I don't know how the addition and scalar multiplication in tensor product space are defined.

If $\alpha\otimes\beta,\gamma\otimes\delta\in V^* \otimes W^*$, what is $\alpha\otimes\beta+\gamma\otimes\delta$? and what is $\phi(\alpha\otimes\beta+\gamma\otimes\delta)$ in $L_2(V \times W,\mathbb{R})$?

Comment: What is your definition of the tensor product of two vector spaces?

Comment: Use the universal property. (This is the *definition* of the tensor product.)

Comment: @Travis I am using the definition [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1116561/clarification-of-definition-of-tensor-product). It is cited from Gallot Riemannian Geometry book.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg I don't quite understand how the universal property is related with the linearity of $\phi$. May you explain more?